# Angular2/Ionic - Find duplicate items in an array and organize them

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2, swiper.js

I have one array that contains multiple elements in a JSON array,
I can access doing by doing `category.language` (there is also few other elements in the JSON that are accessible for example doing `category.name`, `category.photo`, etc)

```
English, Russian, French, Russian, English
```

What I want to do is to put the duplicates with each other and end-up having:

```
English, Russian, French
```

Without removing the duplicates, as removing them will also remove other related elements such as `category.name`... that have other different values.

Currently I am fetching form a REST API, the following is my code:

Page.js

```
    this.menuPages = {
          pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
          //need to have 1 or more (it should some how dynamic depending on the number of the unique items, i.e. sometimes should 1 slide per view, sometimes 10 slides per view )
          slidesPerView: '1',
          paginationClickable: true,
          paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
          console.log('print now2 : '+storeCategory[index]); 
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + storeCategory[index] + '</span>';
          }
      }
```

Page.html

```
  <ion-slides pager [options]="Pages">
          <ion-slide *ngFor="#category of categories">   
     //put the duplicates with each other, to have one element or more in every slide(page)
          <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
          <div class="title">{{category.name}</div>
          <div class="subTitle"><br>{{category.photo}}</div>
          </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

I believe playing around either by `page.html` or `page.js` should solve the issue! I hope you can suggest some ideas to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on exactly what you're asking, but you could use an ES6 set to ensure uniqueness of each entry.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get what you are asking, but here is some code based on what I understood:

```
var pages = {}; // create object to hold the collections
categories.map(cat=>{
        if (!pages[cat.language])
            pages[cat.language]=[];  // create a list for every language
        return cat;
    })
    .forEach(cat=>pages.push(cat)); // push every category to the related list
```

The pages object will have properties named as every language:

```
pages = {
        English:[
            {language:'English',name:'...',photo:'...'},
            {language:'English',name:'...',photo:'...'}
        ],
        Russian:[
            {language:'Russian',name:'...',photo:'...'},
            {language:'Russian',name:'...',photo:'...'}
        ]
    }
```